# Ajax Form Submit appends query strings to url and reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script that submits a form on button click, the script appends the form data to the URL while submitting which isn't safe by any standard, the script works well for other forms except the one am currently debugging. just reloads the page with an annoyingly long URL.

edited: added form method ="post" to the form but still not working. solve url issue though

this is my ajax script:

```
$("form#PostItemz").click(function(){

            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/modules/post_data.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
        });
```

and this is my html form:

```
             <form method="post"  id="PostItemz" class="post publisher-box" >

       <div class="panel panel-white post panel-shadow">
          <div id="post-textarea">
                       <img class="post-avatar" src="profile/maxwell/images (1).jpg">
                      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="loading_indicator"></i>
             <textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this, 70)" onclick="Wo_ShowPosInfo();" name="postText" class="form-control postText" cols="10" rows="3" placeholder="What&#039;s new ? @groups " dir="auto"></textarea> 
          </div>

    <div id="post-status">

      </div>

                <div class="publisher-hidden-option" id="video-form">
             <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                <input name="videocount" id="video_value" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
             </div>
          </div>
                   <!-- ###music widget -->  
                   <div class="publisher-hidden-option" id="music-form"> 
             <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon fa fa-music"></i> 
               <input name="musiccount" type="text" class="form-control" id="audio_value"  readonly>
             </div>
             <div class="create-album pull-right" onclick="Wo_OpenAlbum();">
               <div class="create-text">
                 Add to album     <input name="OkAlbum" value="AddToAlbum" type="checkbox" />      </div>
             </div> 
                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="publisher-hidden-option" id="photo-form" >
             <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon fa fa-file-image-o"></i>
                <input name="phtoscount" id="photo_value" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
             </div>
             <div class="create-album pull-right" onclick="Wo_OpenAlbum();">
               <div class="create-text">
                 Add to album     <input name="OkAlbum" value="AddToAlbum" type="checkbox" />      </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>  
          </div>
          <div class="publisher-hidden-option" id="file-form">
             <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <input name="filename" id = "file_value" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results"></div>
          <div class="publisher-hidden-option">
             <div id="progress">
                <span id="percent">0%</span>
                <div class="progress">
                 <div id="bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="publisher-box-footer">
             <div class="row col-lg-2 pull-right">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-main">
                <i class="fa fa-edit progress-icon "></i> <span id="postbutton">Post</span></button>
             </div>
            <div class="row pull-left">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-camera" ></i><input type="file" id="publisher-photos" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg" name="postPhotos[]" multiple>
                      </span>
                   </div> 
                </div>
             </div>

                      <div class="row pull-left">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i><input type="file" onchange="xVideo();" id="publisher-video" name="postVideo" accept="video/*">
                      </span>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>   
             <div class="row pull-left emo-form" >
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-smile-o "></i>
                      </span>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class="row pull-left">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-file dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
                   <div class="row pull-left">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i><input type="file" onchange="xFile();" id="publisher-file" name="postFile">
                      </span>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>

                      <div class="row pull-left">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <i class="fa fa-music"></i><input type="file" onchange="xAudio();" id="publisher-music" name="postMusic" accept="audio/*">
                      </span>

                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
                 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>


             <div class="input-group">
                <div class="pull-right charsLeft-post"><span id="charsLeft"></span></div>
             </div>
             <div id="status"></div>
                      <div class="row pull-right">
                <div class="poster-left-buttons">
                   <div class="publisher-hidden-option inputsm">
                      <select name="postPrivacy" class="form-control inputsm">
                                                 <option value="3" selected>My Groups</option>
                            <option value="0" >Everyone</option>
                                                    <option value="1" disabled>Private</option>
                                                                   </select>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
             <input type="hidden" name="hash_id" value="c1183f16ab610230ebe8a9bcb331d2d6f7ebbf66">
       <input type="hidden" name="postRecord" value="" id="postRecord">
    </form>
```

all what the script at inc/modules/post_data.php does is to echo "hello world"; but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you add the "annoyingly long URL"?

Comment: `http://localhost/bridgoo/bridgoo%20-%20Copy%20(2).php?postText=zhhzhzh&videocount=&musiccount=&phtoscount=&filename=&postPhotos%5B%5D=&postVideo=&postFile=&postMusic=&postPrivacy=3&hash_id=c1183f16ab610230ebe8a9bcb331d2d6f7ebbf66&postRecord=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add an `event.preventDefault()` line to avoid having the browser perform the default behavior, which is reloading page on submit.

Try something like

```
$("#PostItemz").on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault()
var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/modules/post_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

});
```

This should at least solve the reload issue. Also, if you want to target the form, use **submit** event: `$("#form_id").on('submit', function() {//do stuff})` . If you want to target the button in itself, then you can do `$("#button_id").on('click', function() {//do stuff})` but for a form I'd advise the first solution.

**EDIT**: If you place your code in the head, it loads **before** the rest of the page, thus tries to bind to an ID that does not exists (at the time of processing the script). To avoid this, you should either:

- place the code at the end of the body, just before the `</body>` tag
- use a `$(function() {//stuff})` (shortened for of the
  `$(document).on('ready', function() {//do stuff})` ) to wrap up your
  jquery code, essentially telling the browser: "wait for the full page
  to load before executing this script"

The later translates as the following code in your case:

```
$(function() {
$("#PostItemz").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/modules/post_data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: tried but event.preventDefault still not working, chrome still reloads the page and not response from server

Comment: Strange... I just tested what I gave you above (with another php page though) and the page does not reload, as intended. Did you try to take out all the ajax and simply log a message in the console inside the on('submit') function? Where is your javascript code placed (in the head or body)? --it seems that the function just does not trigger in the first place, which could be a consequence of the js loading _before_ the html and thus not binding to it

Comment: i placed the js in the head... could this be my flaw? loading the ajax before the html dom?

Comment: Ok, so try my new edit then, hopefully that should help. I personally do not like placing js in the head, because you then have to think about wrapping all your code in some $(document).on('ready') equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't click a form, you submit it

```
$("#PostItemz").on('submit', function(){

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'inc/modules/post_data.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : formData,
        success : function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: without a submit button, i used a button to trigger #postItemz.submit() but onsubmit listeners didnt kick in or the script not responding, no errors on console too

Comment: You have a submit button? A `<button>` element with no specified type, has a default type of  `submit` and will submit the form, hence why it reloads the page when you click it.

Comment: And thinking about it, you actually need those options that keeps jQuery from processing the form, but `async:false` is deprecated, and shouldn't be used, ***ever***, and `cache : false` is the default.

Comment: any async: false alternative? which version of jquery deprecates it. must have missed that too

Comment: It's not really jQuery, it's the browser that have deprecated synchronous ajax, as it shouldn't be used